# how to add a drop up list to floating button

Tags: html, css, dropdown, floating-action-button

I have a floating button in my html page

```css
.float{
  position:fixed;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  bottom:40px;
  right:40px;
  background-color:#0C9;
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}

.my-float{
  margin-top:22px;
}


.label-container{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:48px;
  right:105px;
  display:table;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-text{
  color:#FFF;
  background:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.label-arrow{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:#333;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.my-float{
  font-size:24px;
  margin-top:18px;
}

a.float + div.label-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

a.float:hover + div.label-container{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.float:hover .user-req-list {
  visibility: collapse;
}


.float{
  position:fixed;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  bottom:40px;
  right:40px;
  background-color:#0C9;
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}

.my-float{
  margin-top:22px;
}


.label-container{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:48px;
  right:105px;
  display:table;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-text{
  color:#FFF;
  background:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.label-arrow{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:#333;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.my-float{
  font-size:24px;
  margin-top:18px;
}

a.float + div.label-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

a.float:hover + div.label-container{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.float:hover .user-req-list {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a class="float">
    <i class="fa fa-plus my-float"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="label-container">
    <div class="label-text">User Join Requests</div>
    <i class="fa fa-play label-arrow"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to add to this button a dropup list so when I press/hover on it the list will appear and the user will be able to interact with it.
I tried to add a drop down from bootstrap like I saw in [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) however the list didn't show as you can see here

```css
.float{
  position:fixed;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  bottom:40px;
  right:40px;
  background-color:#0C9;
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}

.my-float{
  margin-top:22px;
}


.label-container{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:48px;
  right:105px;
  display:table;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-text{
  color:#FFF;
  background:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.label-arrow{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:#333;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.my-float{
  font-size:24px;
  margin-top:18px;
}

a.float + div.label-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

a.float:hover + div.label-container{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.float:hover .user-req-list {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.user-req-list {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="float dropdown-toggle"  role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-plus my-float"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="label-container">
      <div class="label-text">User Join Requests</div>
      <i class="fa fa-play label-arrow"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

as you can see it didn't work , the list doesn't show when I hover over the button. is there any way to do what I want?
also note that my project is in angular 6 so any javascript is mostly out of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code is working. you just didn't added JS requirements for dropdowns. [See documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

> Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js. Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.

However, note that the dropdown won't be accessible hovering your button. According to [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#overview), this is [an intentional design decision.](http://markdotto.com/2012/02/27/bootstrap-explained-dropdowns/)

```css
.float{
  position:fixed;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  bottom:40px;
  right:40px;
  background-color:#0C9;
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}

.my-float{
  margin-top:22px;
}


.label-container{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:48px;
  right:105px;
  display:table;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-text{
  color:#FFF;
  background:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.label-arrow{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:#333;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.my-float{
  font-size:24px;
  margin-top:18px;
}

a.float + div.label-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

a.float:hover + div.label-container{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.float:hover .user-req-list {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.user-req-list {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="float dropdown-toggle"  role="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
     aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-plus my-float"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="label-container">
    <div class="label-text">User Join Requests</div>
    <i class="fa fa-play label-arrow"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well I added popper.js using npm i popper.js and then I added in the angular.json file a script "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js", the dorpdown indeed show but it doesn't stick to the button like in your example rather it go on the end of the page, what am I missing?

Comment: Added this to my site, dropdown works but it breaks my whole css style for the site when i add bootstap css<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
what can i do to avoid overriding styles?